# PHPMyadmin string displayed differently in binary

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

In PHPMyadmin database, I have a table stores data in string that I imported from a csv file. Everything seems to be okay. Values displayed correctly 
eg : 'KyTyj0304'

But when I run a query which is very simple :

```
select * from myTable where column ='KyTyj0304'
```

It returns 0 row.
When I change Type or Collation to Binary, it displays a string very strange : '0x004b7954796a30323036'

Can someone please help me, and advise which type or collation I would use for my tables?

Many thanks.

Comment: What is the current structure of your table?

Comment: `column`? did you change column name there? show the current structure of table to us. (Add in your question)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your questions. Finally I put all columns, all database to UTF-8, it solved all issues linked to different languages.